# What are the exact functions that cron and anacron tasks perform?

Tags: ubuntu, cron, kubuntu

This maybe irrelevant but my OS is Ubuntu 18.04lts and I've been using KDE plasma 5 (kubuntu). I've been plagued by the possibility that cron and anacron are directly causing the crash of plasmashell specifically while running a video wallpaper for a period of time. I've looked all over the web and am getting sick of hearing about what cron and anacron do and how they can be manipulated. Could someone explain, in an easy to understand way, what the tasks are needed for in the first place? I don't use them and they're (in my eyes) a completely useless set of features to have by default, on and running things that aren't actually needed by the system to function. Why even have either?

Comment: cron and anacron are standard services to do all tasks that are executed on a regular basis, e.g. daily, hourly, at specific times... Why do you think these services are related to the crashes? These services don't do the tasks themselves. Every software that needs regular tasks can use cron or anacron to run the specific tasks as necessary. BTW: You should use neutral language to describe your problems.

Comment: Sorry about language. Is it possible plasmashell could have a call to cron or anacron and that's why it's periodically killing itself? I wrongly related cron and anacron too the crashes because logs show that those are the things running sessions always around the time the desktop crashes.. Thank you for any help you offer, I'm just a microsft baby in a linux world and it's a frustrating one sometimes.